# CUDA Simple Array Search - Shared Memory

Tags: c++, c, cuda

I am writing a function to search for the first occurrence that matches a specific criteria.  In my particular problem, I am interested in finding the array index corresponding to a circle that intersects with a given point.  I have three arrays that collectively describe the circles: x coordinates, y coordinates, and radii (`cx`, `cy`, `cz`).  Given an input point I calculate whether or not it will intersect each of the circles defined by the 3 arrays.  I chose to declare the x, y, radii arrays in global memory because my `search` function will be called often and these arrays will not change.

This function seems pretty straight forward, but I'm getting the following error:

`cudaMemcpy(&res, dev_idx, sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost) returned the launch timed out and was terminated(6)`

```
static void CheckCudaErrorAux (const char *, unsigned, const char *, cudaError_t);
#define HANDLE_ERROR(value) CheckCudaErrorAux(__FILE__,__LINE__, #value, value)

// global memory arrays on the device
__device__ __constant__ double* cx;
__device__ __constant__ double* cy;
__device__ __constant__ double* cr;

__global__ void _cuda_find_containing_circle(double px, double py, int* fidx, int count){
    // px, py: x and y coordinates of the search point
    // fidx:   a device variable to return the index of the matching circle
    // count:  total number of circle elements in the device arrays

    // get the current thread id
    int tid = threadIdx.x + blockIdx.x * blockDim.x;

    if(tid < count){
        // calculate the hypotenuse of the point and grab the radius
        float hypot = (float)hypot(cx[tid] - px, cy[tid] - py);
        float radius = (float)cr[tid];

        // if the hypotenuse is within the radius, return the current index
        // this looks like the problem, i.e. hardcoding to "if(tid = 10){" does not result in an error
        if (hypot <= radius){  
            atomicMin(fidx, tid);

            // I've also tried setting the idx directly
            //*fidx = tid;
        }

        // increment thread id
        tid += blockDim.x * gridDim.x;
    }
}





void main(){
    // define a search point for testing
    int px = 100;
    int py = 150;

    // initialize cx, cy, cz device values using the following arrays
    double *circlex;
    double *circley;
    double *circler;
    int count = 100;

    circlex = (double *) malloc(sizeof(double) * count);
    circley = (double *) malloc(sizeof(double) * count);
    circler = (double *) malloc(sizeof(double) * count);

    // populate arrays with values that will not pass the search criteria
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        circlex[i] = 2.1;
        circley[i] = 3.2;
        circler[i] = 0.0;
    }

    // add a single value that will pass the search criteria (for testing)
    circlex[count - 5] = 101.0;
    circley[count - 5] = 160.0;
    circler[count - 5] = 11.0;  //hypot should result in 10.0498 < 11

    // copy these data onto the device 
    HANDLE_ERROR(cudaMemcpyToSymbol(cx, &circlex, sizeof(circlex), 0, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice));
    HANDLE_ERROR(cudaMemcpyToSymbol(cy, &circley, sizeof(circley), 0, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice));
    HANDLE_ERROR(cudaMemcpyToSymbol(cr, &circler, sizeof(circler), 0, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice));

    // create an object on the device to store the search index result
    int* dev_idx;
    int idx = 999;  // initial condition.  If -999 is returned then I know that a match was not found
    HANDLE_ERROR(cudaMalloc((void **) &dev_idx, sizeof(int)));
    HANDLE_ERROR(cudaMemcpy(dev_idx, &idx, sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice));

    // call the search function
    _cuda_find_containing_circle <<<128, 128>>> (px, py, dev_idx, count);

    // get the search result
    // this line throws the following error: cudaMemcpy(&res, dev_idx, sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost) returned the launch timed out and was terminated(6) 
    int res;
    HANDLE_ERROR(cudaMemcpy(&res, dev_idx, sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost));

    cout << "IDX = " << res << endl;





static void CheckCudaErrorAux (const char *file, unsigned line, const char *statement, cudaError_t err)
{
    if (err == cudaSuccess)
        return;
    std::cerr << statement<<" returned " << cudaGetErrorString(err) << "("<<err<< ") at "<<file<<":"<<line << std::endl;
    exit (1);
}
```

Is there something fundamentally incorrect with my approach?

Comment: Your use of the three `__constant__` pointers is totally broken in several ways.

Comment: @talonmies Can you please explain?  Is it because they are declared as `double*` rather than something like `double[N]` ?

Comment: Nowhere do you allocate any memory for them. You just copy an (illegal) host address to the symbols

Comment: I have added a community wiki answer to this question to get it off the unanswered list. If you are satisfied with it, perhaps you could accept it, just to get this question off the unanswered list. Otherwise, add you own answer if you found a better solution yourself, or perhaps delete the question

Answer (score 1):

The core problem is this:

```
cudaMemcpyToSymbol(cx, &circlex, sizeof(circlex), 0, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
```

`cx` is a unintialised pointer to which you are copying `sizeof(double *)` bytes from a source array of double values, leaving it containing a nonsense address which results in an illegal memory operation in your kernel.

Do something like this instead:

```
 double * _cx; cudaMalloc((void **)&_cx, sizeof(double) * count);
 cudaMemcpy(_cx, circlex, sizeof(double) * count, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
 cudaMemcpyToSymbol(cx, &_cx, sizeof(_cx));
```

i.e. allocate a device memory buffer, copy the host source data to that buffer, then copy the address of that buffer to the constant memory pointer.